# Search function is not working in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, erb

I am creating  a form for my posts search. I am doing like this ....

erb form code...

```
<%= form_tag '/posts/search-post', :remote=> "true" do %>
 <p>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :placeholder => "Search Posts..." %><br/>
  <%= radio_button_tag :day, 1, params[:day] %>None
  <%= radio_button_tag :day, 2, params[:day] %>Last Week
  <%= radio_button_tag :day, 3, params[:day] %>Last Month<br/>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :onclick => "document.getElementById('spinner').style.visibility='visible';document.getElementById('postlist').style.visibility='hidden'" %>
 </p>
<% end %>
```

root.rb

```
match 'posts/search-post', to: 'posts#search_post'
```

posts_controller.rb

```
  def search_post
    if !params[:search].blank? && params[:day].blank?
     @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5).search(params[:search])
   elsif params[:search].blank? && !params[:day].blank?
     @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5).all   if params[:day] == "1"
     @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5).where("created_at >= ?", 1.week.ago.utc)   if params[:day] == "2"
     @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5).where("created_at >= ?", 1.month.ago.utc)   if params[:day] == "3"
   elsif !params[:search].blank? && !params[:day].blank?
     @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5).search(params[:search]) if params[:day] == "1"
     @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5).search(params[:search]).where("created_at >= ?", 1.week.ago.utc)   if params[:day] == "2"
     @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5).search(params[:search]).where("created_at >= ?", 1.month.ago.utc)   if params[:day] == "3"    
   else
   end 
  end
```

Post.rb model

```
  def self.search(search)
    search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['lower(content) LIKE ? OR lower(title) LIKE ?', search_condition.downcase,search_condition.downcase])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

search-post.js.erb

```
$("#posts_list").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => "posts") ) %>");
```

When I search by both keyword and day type then searching is not working (Getting all post list-items). I don't know where i am wrong. Please help.

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: when both field (search & day field) is not blank then searching is not working ( 'AND' operation is not working).

Comment: "searching is not working" - Means you are getting an error or are u getting wrong or no data?

Comment: I am getting all post list-item

Comment: According to ur code, if both params[:search] and params[:day] are present, and params[:day] is not '1', you are ignoring params[:search]

Comment: sorry i forgot to post my update code

Comment: Are you sure both params are present? If both are absent, the control will come to else part.

Comment: @santhosh you got a right point. if both params are blank it will go to else part. I will add this condition also. but i check my search by filling both fields

Comment: If you show the log info for a search it would be useful

Comment: Its working on heroku

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you've done this intentionally, but in both your `elseif` and `else` sections in your controller, you're overwriting your search results.

For example, in your `else` section, you first do this:

```
@posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5).search(params[:search]) if params[:day] == "1"
```

and then you do this:

```
@posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5).where("created_at >= ?", 1.week.ago.utc)   if params[:day] == "2"
```

Which means that the second set of results that are saved in @posts will overwrite your first set of results (what was saved in @posts in your first line).

Since you're doing an "&&" operation, then you should include your result set from your first line into the second.

One solution to your problem might be to change your Post.rb model to something like this:

```
def self.search(search, previous_results_set)
    search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
    if search
      if previous_result_set.nil?
        find(:all, :conditions => ['lower(content) LIKE ? OR lower(title) LIKE ?', search_condition.downcase,search_condition.downcase])
      else
        previous_result_set.find(:all, :conditions => ['lower(content) LIKE ? OR lower(title) LIKE ?', search_condition.downcase,search_condition.downcase])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

My code might not be perfect and you can probably find a more efficient way of doing it in your code, but you get the idea. Even when you user the `.where`, you need to perform the `.where` on the previous result set, not on the `Post` model as a whole again. That way you will be filtering your previously filtered results.

Hope this helps.